# ¿Como guardar array de select Mariadb y guardar valores en distintas variables(no el arreglo completo) PHP?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Hola tengo una función que retorna un array pero quiero acceder por medio de sus indices al valor que quiera de los campos seleccionados en la base de datos por ejemplo guardar en la variable a el indice [0] en otras palabras el primer valor del arreglo y en la variable b guardar el indice [1] etcétera. Este es mi codigo pensaba que trabajar con arrays era cuestión de usar indices.

```
class Tabla{
    public function salida_materiales() {
            try {
                $orden_de_compra = $_GET['orden_de_compra'];

                include("resource/Database.php");
                $sql = "SELECT folio, fecha, numero_remision ,numero_factura,otro,referencia_transporte ,placa_tractor,placa_caja,comentarios,retorno,
    fecha_posible  FROM salida_materiales WHERE orden_de_compra= :orden_de_compra";
                        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                            $query->bindparam(':orden_de_compra', $orden_de_compra);




                $query->execute();
                $tabla = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                //echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage();
                $result = false;
            }
            $query = null;
            $db = null;
            return $tabla;        
        }

}
```

Llamo a la funcion y no me guarda el valor

```
 $tabla = new Tabla();
    $arreglo = $tabla->salida_materiales();
    $folio = $arreglo[0];
```

y asi si quisiera mas variables del array obtenido por la consulta, por cierto ya protegi mi codigo contra la inyeccion sql gracias a la recomendacion de un usuario de esta pagina.

Comment: Al hacer esto: `$tabla = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` obtienes en la variable `$tabla` un array asociativo de los datos. Luego lo puedes leer en un bucle, por ejemplo: `$arreglo = $tabla->salida_materiales(); foreach ($arreglo as $row){$folio=$row["folio"]; //Y así con las otras columnas}` O, si quieres imprimir claves y valores del array: `foreach ($arreglo as $k=>$v){echo $k.": ".$v;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te puede servir:

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las
>   columnas del conjunto de resultados.
>
> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (predeterminado): devuelve un array indexado tanto por
>   nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0 tal como
>   fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados.
>
> PDO::FETCH_NUM: devuelve un array indexado por el número de columna
>   tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados, comenzando por la
>   columna 0.

Usa FETCH_BOTH o FETCH_NUM.

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolvi hace rato con tu informacion lo hice de esta manera                        $tabla = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 $folio = $arreglo[0][0]; //Aunque no entiendo el porque lleva dos ceros pense que el indice es un subarray lo que devuelve de la base de datos? porque al principio intente  asi $arreglo[0] y no funciono, debi poner atencion a mi maestra cuando hablo de arrays ha

Answer (score 1):

Como usaste PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, el resultado te lo pondrá indexado según el nombre de las columnas. Además, vas a tener uno de esos arreglos por cada fila del resultado.

Así que la forma correcta de leer la columna *folio* es:

```
$tabla = new Tabla();
$arreglo = $tabla->salida_materiales();
$folio = $arreglo[0]['folio']; // primer folio encontrado.
```

También puedes imprimir el resultado para ver la estructura: `print_r($arreglo);`

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta es otra forma de realizarlo